# use private key authentication with ms fabric sftp connector

Tags: azure-data-factory, sftp, connector, microsoft-fabric

I'm trying to build an end to end analytics flow in Microsoft Fabric, using the fabric data factory to read files on an sftp server and load them to onelake so I can then push into datasets and report on them in power bi.

The **fabric** SFTP connector only has basic authentication:

[image]

, but I need to use a private keyfile and SSH auth instead

In **Azure** Data Factory, the sftp connector allows SSH auth & keyfiles:

[image]

Is there a different connector I could / should use in fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [Ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-factory/connector-sftp-overview)

> only Basic authentication is supported for SFTP connector in Microsoft Fabric.
>
> > [image]

If you only want to authenticate with the SSH auth & key files you need to use ADF.

You can raise a feature request about adding authentication options for SFTP connector as ADF [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/).